# Find simultaneous connection through wireshark

Tags: browser, connection, wireshark, simultaneous

Just finish reading Steve Souder's blog post related to max. simultaneous connection allow on modern browser.  I wanted to see for myself on how many simultaneous connection firefox uses to connect to our company web site.  In Steve's blog, in mentioned that he was able to find out the number of simultaneous connection through some kind of packet sniffer.  So I went and downloaded WireShark, and were able to capture the TCP packets made to my company's web site.  However, how do I know how many connection were made simultaneously?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter by source IP address. Assuming that your test PC only runs Firefox and no other browsers are open then the number of connections from that PC is the number of connections Firefox is creating to your site.

To know if they are simultaneous check the start of socket creation and the termination of sockets.